# Java compiler not installed on this system

Tags: java

I use CodeBlocks.

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|

||error: C:\Users\Desktop\java\T1.java: Java compiler not installed on this system|

||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, help us help you- share you code snippet and commands you are using to compile and run the program.

Comment: so do you have a JDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

To compile your own java code in your machine, you need a *compiler*, which will convert your code into code that can be understood and executed by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

You can obtain a compiler with the Java Development Kit (JDK), there are many to choose according to the version of java you'll be writing in, you can find the downloads for the Java Standard Edition development kits [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) and further reference on how to set up your environment for java development [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/).

You should also try to provide more information on what exactly your problem is and what have you tried so far in order to fix whatever it might be, the more information you give, the easier and the better the help you get will be.